# I may / may not be interested based on something, but I don't have the opportunity to ask

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

When you do get an opportunity through the SO jobs you are sent a message from the employer.  After reading it you are put in a rather odd position to state whether **I'm Interested** or **I'm Not Interested**...

We need one more status as such:

[image]

We need an **Ask a question** button.  I don't know if I want to show all my cards yet, so allow me to ask a question and get some solid information before I commit to even talking to this employer.

Comment: The "I'm interested" button is not a commitment to take the job. If you have questions about the job, you clearly have *some* interest in finding out more. If you have no questions, hit the "I'm not interested" button and you won't hear anything more about it.

Comment: @AlexWarren - But I think it's very misleading...I won't be interested until after I've verified and confirmed several questions I have.  I'm not interested just yet and I won't be interested until after the employer has answered my questions.  Until that point I am neither interested nor not interested.  Maybe what he tells me I like to hear, then I am interested...or it could work the other way I might hate hearing it...

Comment: You're not expressing irrevocable interest for all time. It's fine if your interest goes away after hearing back from them. The buttons are asking if you're interested right now.

Comment: `You're not expressing irrevocable interest for all time.` but the button is *super bright green.* I agree that a neutral "ask a question" button might be a good idea

Comment: @AlexWarren - But its very misleading...I got the opportunity and the UI presents to me two buttons which fail to address just that.  To you, the developer, you know behind that button it doesn't mean commitment.  Take yourself out of the story for a minute and focus on the end user.  If I present to you a UI that asks a question with two buttons, one yes and one no, and in your mind you are thinking but wait a minute..I cannot answer that question..what do you do?

Comment: In other words, if you aren't interested at the time, you clearly wouldn't be asking any questions.

Comment: @Josh intellectually speaking, totally. But that's splitting hairs. A UI is supposed to be used without much thinking.

Comment: The word "interested" means "showing curiosity or concern about something or someone; having a feeling of interest".

Comment: @Pekka - Exactly, If I have to think twice about it...and I'm at that point right now as a real end user I won't answer this employer until something is fixed because right now I'm not interested but I'm also NOT not interested.

Comment: @AlexWarren - Right and I'm not having that feeling until someone confirms a few of my questions.  In fact, I won't answer this guy until it's clear to me that he knows I need some questions answered.

Comment: If an "Ask a question" button was added, I assume it would have the exact same functionality as the "I'm interested" button, right? They would essentially just be synonyms, right? Or are you concerned about the fact that the employer sees that you're 'interested' and may confuse that with commitment?

Comment: To me a couple of things need to be changed.  If you cannot have 3 states (Interested, Not Interested, and Maybe) then you need to get rid of the green color which screams YES IM ALL IN...and make it neutural.  You then need to rephrase it to say, "I have questions"...see what I mean we are back to square one..This cannot be solved with just two states.  You need that third state to allow me to talk to the employer without being all in.  You may be focusing on the actual code / events because you know what happens..it flows for you.  But it doesn't flow for outsiders, and even if it did the...

Comment: cont...the ux is not presented (currently) in a form that doesn't make you think twice.

Comment: @JonH Rather than [I'm interested], what about [Reply] and [I'm not interested] ? Clicking [Reply] would imply that you have questions, or that you're interested.

Comment: @JoshCrozier - That would make sense, again you have to either change the terminology (to allow for only 2 states).  Or if you are not willing to change the terminology at this point you need 3 states.

Comment: What if the terminology was changed from "I'm Interested" to "I'd like to know more"?  Then you capture the intent of wanting more information with less of the "all in, sign me up and sell my soul now" feel.

Comment: @Becuzz - Similiar to Josh's remark above.  You either tweak the wording to maintain two states if they really want to keep two states or you simply add another state (a button) allowing a maybe...

Comment: Not realizing that there was already a question here, I make the same complaint [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273686/interested-not-interested-is-a-false-dichotomy)

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between not enough information and "interested". There may not be for dev. workflow, but that is hardly the point. This forces users to choose between things they don't want. Even if the labels were changed to "continue conversation" and "end conversation" that would be a superior user experience. Heck, even if the new button DID EXACTLY THE SAME THING that would be a superior experience.

Comment: There should be an understanding that the "I'm interested" part of the workflow is completely black-boxed after someone clicks "I'm interested." For all we know, you're sending emails to employers saying "THIS PERSON SAYS HE IS INTERESTED. YOU SHOULD MAKE HIM AN OFFER TODAY!" There are clear problems with that being the message.

Comment: I agree with @cwallenpoole, heck the comments alone should indicate that a change is needed.

Comment: And that is much of what this discussion is about — messaging. I don't want to send an "interested" message to a company who wants to hire me for a 3 month contract at $20/hr, but I might be interested in a "Great opportunity with massive startup" (even if that is the jobs equivalent of click-bait) and there is nothing saying that a company can't claim to be "great" and have a bad offer.

Comment: AND FURTHERMORE, the options are "Not interested, don't even send a reply" and "Interested".