# "I'm Interested" and "I'm Not Interested" are not properly aligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

This happens on the jobs messages page (https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages) in the inbox. On the below screenshot, the "I'm Not Interested" button is a bit lower than the "I'm Interested" button.

[image]

Reproduced in Chrome 48 on Mac OS X.

Comment: This is horrible.

Comment: Not only is it horrible, its ambiguous because I might not be either...and I posted about this quite a long time ago.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314719/i-may-may-not-be-interested-based-on-something-but-i-dont-have-the-opportuni

Comment: [status: by design]: we want you to be more interested than not - NOT!

Comment: Seems like they weren't interested in writing proper CSS ;)

Comment: stop nitpicking :P

Comment: Now you've pointed this out I can't help but notice it.... arrghhh my eyes!

Comment: I was happily playing in life, now this... the weight, the weight upon my shoulders.

Comment: -1 for not having a freehand drawn red circle where the alignment problem is.

Comment: *spasmic twitching of the eye* fix it, now!

Comment: I have a very weird and bad feeling when I look to these buttons

Comment: I actually like it this way, makes my heart skip a beat everytime i see this! (They want to see the world burn.)

Comment: Of course it's status by design. This and any CSS changes must have went through some form of QA/QE, right??

Comment: @MsYvette I like that stylish arrow you've added, it fits in this perfect picture nicely, thanks.

Comment: @alecxe you're welcome :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well spotted! Thank you for the report, @alecxe! :)

There was a major update on all the buttons couple of days back and that is probably when this little bug creeped in. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Great, and we still need this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314719/i-may-may-not-be-interested-based-on-something-but-i-dont-have-the-opportuni