# Company is spamming careers

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

One company deletes and recreates their five job listings every week.

This is going on for about five month and it is really annoying to get these mails. (Nobody wants to work for them, duuh I wonder why)

I did flag them already. Can I do more?

Comment: Unfortunately this is normal behaviour on recruitment websites. Many of the UK ones re-upload all their vacancies every Monday morning ... or send you daily emails with the title "n new matching jobs" when the last new one was several days ago.

Comment: True  - but Careers.SE's promise is to nuke this kind of activity from orbit.

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's the only way to be sure...

Comment: Sounds more like a misunderstanding of how Careers works to me, and how it's different to other job finding sites.

Comment: Are you sure the company doesn't have that QUICK personnel turnover?

Comment: @DeerHunter Doesn't sound like you can have a career there if that's the case...

Comment: Is the company Hormel?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow exactly what's happening here. Are you saying that the same company keeps messaging you via Careers even though you reply "not interested"? Or do you have a job alert email or RSS feed set up and you continually see the same job listings from the same company?

Comment: Should jobs have up- and down-voting like all other SE sites?

Comment: No sense in hiding the name of the company..

Comment: @CQM I was responding to Deer Hunter's comment, which was clearly a joke. I made another joke in turn.

Comment: `Nobody wants to work for them`

Comment: @DavidPostill And this behavior should be killed ASAP. History repeats itself (unless we do something about it): [The 1998 Russ Alberry Usenet rant](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/writing/rant.html). At the time, you saw those jobs newsgroups getting wiped out by a*holes in less than a year.

Answer (score 37):

Basically, when Careers sends you a notification, there really need to be three responses:

- I'm interested in this position.
- I'm not interested in this position, but keep showing me results from this company.
- I'm not interested in this position *or* in any future positions at this company

And future job alerts / feeds need to take those responses into account.

It is just reality that some people have a complete culture clash with certain prospective employers that are completely unrelated to the particulars of the opening, and can never see themselves working for that company no matter what job description opens up.

Comment: While I agree with this, it doesn't solve the problem of spam in general, just for yourself. I think the right answer to the original question is "no," with the addendum that ideally there would be three options, etc.

Comment: @qpaystaxes well the statistics on how many users select to block that company could be useful too.  Maybe they mean the company is a total scam, maybe they mean the company is not paying attention to user profiles before messaging them, maybe the company is pulling dumb tricks like creating the same opening over and over.  All of these will result in a high block rate.

Comment: AFAIK that's what flagging is already for.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Flagging can work, but it's a very different signal than statistics.  Flagging has a hard time ignoring a handful of social justice warriors out to get a company's ads taken down because of the company's involvement in some politically-charged issue.  A major problem with flagging is that it is unsigned feedback -- there's no way for users to say "yes, I love the idea of working in this kind of culture" and no way to measure consensus.

Comment: I think framing this particular case as a "culture clash" is whitewashing the problem behaviour of the company. However, I also think that the proposed solution could help with this case, and maybe more.

Comment: An SE user might not have a culture clash with such a company if the offender is someone from Human Resources who doesn't understand SE. The user might not want to block the company, but would want to discourage the spamming. My ideal company would conform after being notified that the behavior doesn't fit with SE culture, but maybe I wouldn't want to be the one to send that message. A possible solution would be for SE to make the point that the solutions to the spam are for the company to stop doing it or users who don't want to block the company will have to or some other penalty from SE.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: Do you think I need to spell out "What you can do is... file a feature-request to (everything in my answer)."?

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, I think someone needs to look into the behaviour and activity of this company.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: Be realistic.  Whatever company is paying Stack Overflow handsomely for those listings.  For the obvious financial reasons, as well as technical reasons, the SO staff aren't going to investigate their customer employers from a single complaint about non-criminal behavior.  They need evidence of a large fraction of the users reached by that company's ad being dissatisfied by it, and flagging doesn't provide that.  Flags are a good way to handle outright violations of law and contract, not so much for just plain orneriness.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That comment might make a good answer.

Comment: Hah the number of times I've asked for this functionality...in fact here is just one...http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314719/i-may-may-not-be-interested-based-on-something-but-i-dont-have-the-opportuni get ready to get stoned to death.

Comment: @JonH: Your link is about finer grained responses of positive interest, which is the opposite of what is needed to deal with this (finer grained responses of negative interest, and applying them to alerts as well as direct contact)

Comment: @BenVoigt - True but closely related that its a finer way to do things..in both cases.

Comment: Keeping statistics, or allowing feedback, and making this available to the ad-poster should be enough to cause most companies to correct themselves. This would be positive for both job-seekers and employers.

Comment: I disabled notifications on just about every job site I have ever signed up with just because of this spammy behavior. Sad to see SO Careers allowing it as well.

Answer (score 11):

Not to take away from @BenVoigt and his feature request (almost exactly what LinkedIn provides as generic responses to InMail which I utilize all three), but perhaps this is something that can be solved by better communication to these companies about the features of Careers.SE.

As pointed out by @DavidPostill a majority of the careers sites out there reward this type of behavior by keeping their postings "fresh" and near the top of the search results.  It also is an indicator to the job seeker that the position is still available and unfilled since job postings can survive out there for days and not everyone is good about removing postings for filled positions.  Both sides are somewhat conditioned to expect this kind of behavior on those types of sites.

By communicating with employers that Careers.SE is different than other sites and how they can get the most out of their postings they will feel they're getting better bang for their buck and might change their behavior to account for that.  Should be fairly straightforward to find these types of trends and send out a canned email to the effect of:

> Hey, we notice you're doing this thing that everyone on every other job site does and that's cool, thank you for being involved and trying your best to get the attention of the candidates you're after.  We're different here at Careers.SE and we try to cut out this annoying and tedious step for you while still keeping your postings fresh and available.  (point to various features, upsell on sponsored postings, etc)
>
> We've found that by leveraging some of these features companies tend to convert at the same if not better level and it saves you time and effort in the process.  Should you have any questions about the features please feel free to reach out to us at any time.  As always, thanks for being a valued customer and good luck in your current and future candidate searches!

It's not going to eliminate the behavior, but might help reduce it and try to get everyone more involved.  Not to mention it's a good marketing ploy for SE to try to make a little extra in the process of addressing a community concern.

Comment: The basis of a good idea, but I lost you at "point to various features" because I do not know what features, if any, apply to a company here that wants to reach more candidates and thinks it is actually getting something useful (i.e. better visibility of their open jobs) from their current behaviour. Is it possible to explain one feature that you know of here that could apply as an example?

Comment: @NeilSlater I think the point was to show the email, not list other options.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: The email will fall flat if there are no Careers.SE features that do "still keeping your postings fresh and available" that compete with or replace the re-post-same-job ritual (in the target companies eyes, not in ours). I could really support a positive message "why not do this good thing?" vibe as opposed to "don't do this bad thing" one, but is really important that the good thing actually exists. Otherwise it is wishful thinking that sending out a "fluff" email that doesn't address the imagined need will cause any change in behaviour.

Comment: @NeilSlater I agree wholeheartedly, but it's not Foosh'a job to come up with the perfect email. It's SE's job. Foosh just gave them an idea for what they could do and left the details to be filled in.

Comment: @NeilSlater, QPaysTaxes hit it exactly on the head.  I'm by no means an expert on the features of Careers.SE especially on the recruitment side of things and there is a good chance those features simply do no exist.  I'm just trying to present a solution to the OP's problem which I also experience.  Every other job site rewards what several job seekers consider to be "bad behavior", this seems like a place where I would expect Careers.SE to stand out or find a way to do so.