# How can I hide all jobs from a certain company?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not interested in working for company X, but the job list is littered with their offers. How can I hide them selectively?

Comment: Very relevant question. The job list offered to me is literally drowned by offers from a company that has mostly (only?) "remote" jobs for what can be only described as simply outrageously insulting salaries, sometimes for jobs that require seasoned specialist craftmanship. I guess this is targetted to desperate developers from the popular democratic republic of Softwaristan ready to work for a dime, good luck to them them but this is just plain noise to me.

Comment: Tons of question about (against?) this _company_ here on meta. It seems SO can't exclude them (for good reasons) but at least it may be truly nice to give us the opportunity to ignore that _company_. Many people even doubt about its reliability and it's now more spam than useful.

Comment: @jbm: The job list is regularly presenting me with jobs from the company I already work for...

Comment: related? [Company is spamming careers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318845/company-is-spamming-careers)

Comment: If this question is related as @gnat suggested, there is an unanswered question as to how they are spamming [over here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318845/company-is-spamming-careers#comment321067_318845).

Comment: @jbm I'd be interested in a link, just to have a giggle.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You should apply and see if you get a better offer. And maybe you will also get a signing bonus for referring yourself.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti "It seems SO can't exclude them" is **not** true. "Visitors hate seeing your shady listings" would be a perfectly legitimate and legal reason to stop taking $company's money and stop showing their crappy listings. It would not be discriminating against any protected class.

Comment: @AndrewMedico it's not that easy. SO team already expressed their point of view about this (here on meta) but in short: you sell a service and anyone can buy it, you can't (and they don't want) to exclude someone because some (most?) users don't like them. Their example is: company X complains about employee Y. We won't exclude Y. For the same reason if Y complains about X we won't exclude X. That said don't forget that it's always about...money. What they may (should?) do is to stop annoying behaviors (or give us good management tools...even just a simple _blacklist_).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti My point is just that "can't" is the wrong word. They *could* if they wanted to - they just don't *want* to.

Comment: Funny how they were all "we're different! we're better than all the jobs sites before! trust us!" at the beginning, but now that the money is flowing it turns out they're really not different at all.

Comment: @AndrewMedico ahahhahaha yes, they _don't want_, that's true! I'm not sure it's perfectly legal to _ban_ that company but their behavior (and probably site policies) may give them some caveat...

Comment: I just noticed this very nice new feature (for job ads that appear on the main page):  [Allow Users To Hide Individual Job Listings](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312509/allow-users-to-hide-individual-job-listings)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the [search syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/help) to do so. For example, here is Seattle minus Amazon: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=-company%3Aamazon&location=seattle

You can also [dismiss individual job listings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331771/17373) in the side bar ads.

Comment: "For example", eh?  :-)

Comment: How does one do this outside of the search?  This is closely related to this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318971/how-to-get-job-alerts-for-a-specific-company in that these features are tucked away.

Comment: @MattSherman would it be possible to update your answer to point to what the correct search syntax web page is?  The link that's currently there is broken.