# How to get job alerts for a specific company

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When searching for jobs you can create an alert based on the job's tab but it doesn't seem like you can do that for a company, why?

Feature Request, either on the company tab or the actual company page allow me to create a job update alert for a **specific company**.

For instance, say I really like a specific company but for some reason or another the job I applied for did not work out for me (I didn't get the job...either because they find another candidate or I was [left in limbo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314031/didnt-get-the-job-or-did-i-but-in-limbo-what-are-you-guys-doing-to-pro) which to this day several jobs are still in limbo mental note that this needs to be fixed asap).

I'm still interested in company X and anytime they post a new job I'd like some sort of notification.  This helps me re-apply or at least get up to speed on what positions or technologies this said company is using.

Please add this to the company page under available jobs, something to the effect of a hyperlink stating:

"Get job updates from company X"

Also please add this same functionality to the company tab within jobs.  Right now when you search for a job there is no available actions such as signing up a for an alert.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: ability to get job alerts for a specific company (through an improved user experience) is coming soon. We're in the final build phases of our job search feature.

---

You can currently sign up company-specific alerts w/ Jobs search: if you type `company:"stack overflow"` in the Keywords field, you can then set up an alert for jobs at Stack Overflow (or your preferred company).

I agree that it'd be useful to offer this functionality on company pages and company search as well. We're currently working on further improvements to job alerts, so we'll consider for future iterations. Setting as status-deferred for now, since this specific change has not yet been considered or planned for by the team.

Thanks for the note!

Comment: These magical ways of doing things are not intuitive.  Yes I know you can do it this way but do you really believe from an outsider this is intuitive?

Comment: @JonH Never said it was intuitive :) Just letting you know that a solution to this problem exists: "I'm still interested in company X and anytime they post a new job I'd like some sort of notification."

Comment: It exists?  Aside from the non intuitive approach where does this exist?  Or is the non-intuitive approach the approach?  I hope you see where I am getting with this.  Most of these little tricks or tips are highly unlikely users or even power users know exist because they are tucked away, and their fixes are quite simple - add a button on the company page that allows this.