# Why can't I change my SO Jobs interest response in job offer?

Tags: support, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I accidentally clicked "I'm Interested" in the job offer email I received from a recruiter via Stack Overflow Jobs. I am unable to change my response. Why is that not allowed?

**EDIT**: added a screenshot:
[image: Email body interested buttons]

Comment: Sounds like a great feature to add.

Comment: Maybe [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314719/i-may-may-not-be-interested-based-on-something-but-i-dont-have-the-opportuni related

Comment: Good point. Not currently part of our plans but we'll consider when we revisit messaging interactions.