# Way too easy to accidentally click "I'm interested" in emails

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, email

[image]

In an email notification I got from SO, I accidentally clicked the blue "I'm interested" button. Without confirmation, I apparently sent a message to a prospective employer that I was interested when I'm not...  there should at the least be some kind of confirmation to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: What happens if you follow up by clicking "I'm not interested"? :-)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344713/why-cant-i-change-my-so-jobs-interest-response-in-job-offer

Comment: @CodyGray it said I already responded, so it didn't let me change the status (as pointed out by @Keiwan).

Comment: so.... working as intended?

Comment: @JNat if this is not considered a bug, I should just delete my dev profile, since this is definitely an undesirable "feature".

Comment: Your request is definitely a request for a new feature, @Ian: to have a confirmation after you press the button to make sure a message isn't sent when the link is clicked by accident. The button's there, and it's working as intended — unless I'm missing something, your post is not reporting a bug :)

Comment: "It's not a bug, it's a feature."

Comment: I asked about this back in 2016: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314719/i-may-may-not-be-interested-based-on-something-but-i-dont-have-the-opportuni  similiar issue.

Comment: If it doesn't do what the developer thinks it should do, it's a bug.
If it doesn't do what the customer thinks it should do, it's a feature.

Comment: @joe, From the point of view of the customer, it's a misfeature.

Comment: An easy fix would be to swapp the buttons around and have 'not interested' as the higlighted one...

Comment: @RandoHinn an easier fix would be to remove the "I'm interested" button :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski An even easier fix would be to read the text before clicking and confirming in your mind before clicking. :P

Comment: @NisargShah [users don't read](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/26/designing-for-people-who-have-better-things-to-do-with-their-lives/), so your fix is not that easy :P

Comment: @NisargShah apparently you've never mis-clicked anything in your life, have you? Ever used "undo" before, I assume not.

Comment: @Ian I do misclick a lot, but then its a bug in me, not in the software I am using! No offense intended.  :)

Comment: @NisargShah UI must always take into consideration that the user is not perfect and WILL mis-click. Acting like it's all the user's fault is passing the buck for bad/lazy UI.